# Socket.IO clients disconnect randomly

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

We have a turn based card game and has 10K active users daily. We are using socket.io with node.js. But our users are getting too much disconnect which have short time(About one second or two seconds). Our server ping interval is 3000ms, pingTimeout is 12000ms. At the client timeout is 20000ms as default. Our clients are android phones.
How can we solve too much disconnect problem? What do we set our timeouts?

Comment: How many simultaneous users do you have on one server?  And, what are the specs for that server?  Are you using socket.io clustering to involve more processes or servers?  Why are you getting disconnects?  There's way, way, way too little information provided to have any idea what to suggest. You have to figure out WHY you are getting disconnects, not just fiddle with timeout values.  Does the problem occur when there are only a few users active?  Does the problem only occur when the server is heavily loaded?

Comment: We have about 1000 simultaneous users. We are using c5.xlarge from Amazon. It has 4 Cpu, 8Gb ram. But we don't use cluster mode. Our cpu usage are %40-%60. Our client are getting 1-2 seconds disconnect. Why? Because of server-client ping-pong or what else?

Comment: You need to examine client-network traces (you can start in Chrome debugger, network tab) and figure out why they are getting disconnected and whether this is initiated by client or server.  Not much we can do to debug that for you.  Could also probably enable socket.io logging client-side and see what it tells you.  This is a debugging exercise to figure out why you're getting disconnected.  Then, and only then, can we theorize on possible solutions.